# Testing inner functions from component function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a function component and inside it a few another functions (or function expressions). When writing tests, how do I test these inner functions separately?

```
function Component() {
  // How do I test these two?
  const func1 = () => null;
  function func2() {
    return null;
  }
}
```

I want to use Jest as testing framework, so I would do something like this:

```
test("func1", () => {
  expect(func1()).toBe(null);
});
test("func2", () => {
  expect(func2()).toBe(null);
});
```

Comment: You don't. You _can't_, they're not accessible outside the components function, test the _behaviour_ they implement instead.

Comment: But is is a good React practice? For me, it is more convenient and clear to test all functions separately, not the whole component behavior at once. I see that class-based views are more suitable to be used if I don't want to test the whole behavior at once, right?

Comment: Even if you were using a class-based component, so you _could_ call individual methods, you shouldn't. If you test at an appropriate abstraction level you can refactor within the component, including switching between class- and function-based implementations. Interact with the component via the DOM, focus tests on _behaviour_ not implementation details.

Comment: it is good practice, for React or for anything else, to only test the interface of a module by providing input and asserting against the output. in the case of a React component, the input is props and events and API responses and the output is a DOM element.